# Filter on JSONField array

Tags: django, django-mysql

I have a book model

```
class Book():
  ...
  tags=JSONField()
```

I have some records:

```
Book(..., tags=['TECH', 'BUSINESS'])
Book(..., tags=['MARKETING'])
```

I want to filter out the books that have tag 'Tech' or 'Business'

```
query = Q (
    Q(tags__contains='Tech') |
    Q(tags__contains='Business')
)
```

I've tried to use contains, contained_by, has_key, has_any_keys but got no luck.
The result is always empty.

#### Update

It was my mistake!
I found the problem, JSONField is case sensitive.

The values saved in DB were `["TECH", "BUSINESS"]` instead of `["Tech", "Business"]`.

Now the question turns out `How to search in a case-insensitive manner?`

Comment: I've just tried the exact code above and it works just fine for me in Postgresql. Are you using Postgresql?

Comment: @solarissmoke it was my mistake. I've just updated the question

Comment: Your snippet for the model has an error: it should be `tags = JSONField()` instead of `tags: JSONField()`.

Comment: thanks @cezar, just updated. It's my pseudo code.

Comment: Maybe you could implement validation that enforces always all caps terms in the JSONField. That would simplify the things, if the data format is consistent.

Comment: The official documentation for `JSONField()` talks only about key-value pairs. However I would try the [values lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). There are also the [`ArrayField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) examples (for only postgresql) that discuss tags. It does not mention `icontains` though. I can only hope that `icontains` works too.

Comment: What version of Django are you using. In Django 1.11 you can simply do `Q(tags__icontains='Tech')` and it works. This

Comment: I used Django 1.10. Btw, the owner of `django-mysql` confirmed it didn't support icontains yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replied on your issue on the Django-MySQL repo: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/issues/401 . Basically it seems this can't be done as MySQL JSON values are case sensitive only, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitive search can be performed with `icontains`:

```
query = Q(
    Q(tags__icontains='tech') |
    Q(tags__icontains='business')
)
```

Here is a link to the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains).

Comment: I just checked but it threw this exception `Lookup 'icontains' doesn't work with JSONField`. btw, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you're write. I didn't pay attention. That's really annoying!